# Calculate studentized deletion residuals and outlier_test() for the predictions of the OLS

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I am doing iterative outlier elimination with the statmodel OLS. I have fitted the model using.

```
ols_result = sm.OLS(y,X).fit()
```

then i can get the studentized deletion residuals external and bonferroni with

```
ols_result.outlier_test(method="bonf")
```

I am deleting the sample which exceeds bonferroni p > %10 where the cooks distance is also the highest in every iteration. Until i got no sample with bonf(p)>%10 then i got the subset of the original sample.

Let's say i had 400 samples and after outlier deletion i got 380 samples. Now i want to find the studentized deletion residuals and the bonferroni again with the 400 samples with respect to regression fitted for the 380 sample. To see if the deleted outliers are really the outliers.

This is where the problem starts. I was looking for easy way to use statmodels OLS model to get the residuals and the cooks distances for the fitted values instead of writing those functions by myself. But `.outlier_test()` and `.get_influence()` seems to work with OLS Result object.

Do you guys any simple way to achieve those test without too much code etc.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep research for this practicality. I could not find easy way to do it with statmodels library. Instead i wrote my own code also getting help from the statmodels source code. If someone needs the code i am sharing below

```
def internally_studentized_residual(X,Y,y_hat):
    """

    Calculate studentized residuals internal

    Parameters
    ______________________________________________________________________

    X:            List
                  Variable x-axis

    Y:            List
                  Response variable of the X 


    y_hat:        List
                  Predictions of the response variable with the given X

    Returns
    ______________________________________________________________________

    Dataframe :   List
                  Studentized Residuals   


    """

#     print(len(Y))
    X = np.array(X, dtype=float)
    Y = np.array(Y, dtype=float)
    y_hat = np.array(y_hat,dtype=float)
    mean_X = np.mean(X)
    mean_Y = np.mean(Y)
    n = len(X)

#     print(X.shape,Y.shape,y_hat.shape)

    residuals = Y - y_hat

    X_inverse = np.linalg.pinv(X.reshape(-1,1))[0]
    h_ii = X_inverse.T * X

    Var_e = math.sqrt(sum((Y - y_hat) ** 2)/(n-2))
    SE_regression = Var_e/((1-h_ii) ** 0.5)
    studentized_residuals = residuals/SE_regression
    return studentized_residuals

def deleted_studentized_residual(X,Y,y_hat):
    """

    Calculate studentized residuals external

    Parameters
    ______________________________________________________________________

    X:            List
                  Variable x-axis

    Y:            List
                  Response variable of the X 


    y_hat:        List
                  Predictions of the response variable with the given X

    Returns
    ______________________________________________________________________

    Dataframe :   List
                  Studentized Residuals External  


    """
    #formula from https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/401/
    r = internally_studentized_residual(X,Y,y_hat)
    n = len(r)
    return [r_i*math.sqrt((n-2-1)/(n-2-r_i**2)) for r_i in r]


def outlier_test(X,Y,y_hat,alpha=0.1):
    """

    outlier test for the points

    Parameters
    ______________________________________________________________________

    X:            List
                  Variable x-axis

    Y:            List
                  Response variable of the X 


    y_hat:        List
                  Predictions of the response variable with the given X

    alpha:        float
                  alpha value for multiple test

    Returns
    ______________________________________________________________________

    Dataframe :   studentized, unadjusted p values and benferroni multiple 
                  test dataframe  


    """
    resid = deleted_studentized_residual(X,Y,y_hat)
    df = len(X) - 1 
    p_vals = stats.t.sf(np.abs(resid),df) * 2
    bonf_test = multipletests(p_vals,alpha,method="bonf")
    df_result = pd.DataFrame()
    df_result.loc[:,"student_resid"] = resid
    df_result.loc[:,"unadj_p"] = p_vals
    df_result.loc[:,"bonf(p)"] = bonf_test[1]
    df_result.index = X.index

    return df_result
```

it might be a bit dirty code. I did not have time to clean and make it efficient. It uses `numpy` module and `scipy.stats`